# Clef with signature keys, entering other notes

Tags: notation, sheet-music, key-signatures, accidentals

I would like to know, suppose a clef with key signature (e.g., G is always sharp), independent of octave, appears at the beginning of the staff.

Then every G that appears must be read sharp.

Then what do I write, to have the reader read a normal G, or a G flat?

Comment: (I don't think you mean [pentagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram)… Though I'm not aware of any English word for five equidistant parallel lines, other than ‘staff’/‘stave’.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant stave. Why the downvote?

Comment: Votes are anonymous and downvotes are very rarely acknowledged by the person who casts them. I feel it is unjustified in this case so I will give you a +1 to offset it.

Comment: @gidds In Spanish the word “pentagrama” refers to the music staff. This is probably a translation issue.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Ah, that would explain it. (I didn't downvote, BTW.)

Comment: This is a legitimate if unresearched question. Why should beginners know the answer? Of course, it may well be a dupe, but doesn't deserve an unexplained dv (as is usual).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place a natural or flat sign (an "accidental") immediately to the left of the note to be changed.

The below image shows examples of key signatures with G-sharp where the notes themselves are changed to G-natural or G-flat. Once changed, the G on that line or space will remain natural or flat until the end of the measure. After the end of the measure, the key signature takes over. So if another G-natural or G-flat is desired, then another natural or flat sign will need to be placed.

Accidentals affect only the specific line or space on which they're placed. This is also shown in the image below.

[image: Demonstration of accidental usage]

Comment: Anyone who has such an elementary understanding of music theory that they can ask this question and thinks that there is a G flat in a piece they're writing that has a G sharp in the key signature is probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @phoog I think you're being too literal.

Comment: Can you find an example of a professionally engraved piece where a flat is applied to a pitch that is sharp in the key signature, or vice versa?

Comment: @phoog - that hypothetical Gb is far more likely to be F#. Which would be in the key sig. before G# anyway.

Comment: @phoog This happens all the time in late-Romantic music; think Bruckner, etc. Sure, it's advanced stuff, but it definitely happens.

Comment: @phoog OP is just asking how to notate accidentals. However, for a professionally engraved piece with a G-flat in the key signature and a notated G#, take a look at Chopin's [Nocturne in Bb Minor](https://imslp.org/wiki/Nocturnes,_Op.9_(Chopin,_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)), Op. 9, No. 1, m. 3.

Comment: @Richard yes, I've found some examples (specifically, Brückner's Symphony in E major, first movement, measure 42, D flat in the bass instruments).  As I suspected, they are written with ♮♭ instead of just with ♭.

Comment: @phoog Also, m. 4 of Chopin's [G minor Ballade](chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://vmirror.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/3/3a/IMSLP64108-PMLP01646-Chopin_Balades_Schirmer_Mikuli_Op_23_scan.pdf) has an E# against a Bb/Eb key signature.

Answer (score 4):

When there's a sharp in the key signature, say, on the G in the treble clef, it means every G in that piece will be played as a G♯.

To cancel that, there needs to be a natural or flat sign just before the note affected. That will then last until - the end of the bar it's in, or - it's changed by another *accidental* to say what it'll be next. But regardless, in the very next bar, it will need to be played as G♯ again - unless affected by yet another natural or flat sign.

Those accidentals will only affect notes in the particular octave tey're written in - any other G notes in other octaves will still be G♯.